# Magento: Error on checkout

Tags: magento, exception, payment, checkout

I have a problem on Magento Checkout. All payment methods selected on checkout give the message:There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later.

I logged the proces and came up with the next exception.log

I run Magento 1.7.0.2. Where do i start on solving this? Is this a problem with the template i bought? Thank you.

```
    2015-04-07T06:46:34+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Ongeldig bloktype: Mage_Page_Block_Html_CookieNotice' in /home/vhosts/XXXXXX.XX/httpdocs/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vhosts/XXXXXX.XX/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Ongeldig blokty...')
#1 /home/vhosts/XXXXXX.XX/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('page/html_cooki...', Array)
#2 /home/vhosts/XXXXXX.XX/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('page/html_cooki...', 'global_cookie_n...')
#3 /home/vhosts/XXXXXX.XX/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('page/html_cooki...', 'global_cookie_n...')
#4 /home/vhosts/XXXXXX.XX/httpdocs/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(40): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/vhosts/XXXXXX.XX/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/vhosts/XXXXXX.XX/httpdocs/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(31): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#7 /home/vhosts/XXXXXX.XX/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#8 /home/vhosts/XXXXXX.XX/httpdocs/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(31): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#9 /home/vhosts/XXXXXX.XX/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#10 /home/vhosts/XXXXXX.XX/httpdocs/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(31): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#11 /home/vhosts/XXXXXX.XX/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->generateBlocks()
#12 /home/vhosts/XXXXXX.XX/httpdocs/app/code/local/Smartwave/Ajaxcart/controllers/IndexController.php(168): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#13 /home/vhosts/XXXXXX.XX/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Smartwave_Ajaxcart_IndexController->optionsAction()
#14 /home/vhosts/XXXXXX.XX/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('options')
#15 /home/vhosts/XXXXXX.XX/httpdocs/app/code/community/BalkeTechnologies/StoreMaintenance/Controller/Router/Standard.php(91): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /home/vhosts/XXXXXX.XX/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): BalkeTechnologies_StoreMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#17 /home/vhosts/XXXXXX.XX/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#18 /home/vhosts/XXXXXX.XX/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /home/vhosts/XXXXXX.XX/httpdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Block of Type `Mage_Page_Block_Html_CookieNotice` does not exist in Magento 1.7. It was introduced in Magento 1.8.

If you use a bought template check if it is compatible with your used Magento Version. If it is, file a bug report with the developer.

If not you could try to [upgrade you magento version](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_upgrade_landing.html).